# Pandas: Pivot a table using the column names as variables

Tags: pandas, pivot, melt

I have a dataset in which each column represent a different measurement for a specific parameter. The parameter name is the column name.

I have the following sample code:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': (1,2), 'B':(3,4)})
display(df)
    A   B
0   1   3
1   2   4
```

What I would like to obtain is a table like this

```
    Parameter   value
0   A           1
1   A           2
2   B           3
3   B           4
```

I've seen in the documentation that there are pivot_table and melt functions, but I do not know how to apply them in this case.

Comment: try `df.melt()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas melt function is useful to massage a DataFrame into a format where one or more columns are identifier variables (id_vars), while all other columns are considered measured variables (value_vars). For more information, you can check out the docs [Pandas Melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

- "id_vars" accepts a list that should be used as an index when the DataFrame is combined.
- "value_vars" accepts a list that should be used as a value when the DataFrame is combined.

```
   import pandas as pd
   df = pd.DataFrame({'A': (1,2), 'B':(3,4)})
   df = df.melt(value_vars = df.columns.to_list())
   print(df.head())
```

Output would look like this

```
  variable  value
0        A      1
1        A      2
2        B      3
3        B      4
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'A': (1,2), 'B':(3,4)})
pd.melt(df, value_vars=['A', 'B'])
```

Output:

```
    variable    value
0   A           1
1   A           2
2   B           3
3   B           4
```